# How to trim a string from carriage returns in java

Tags: java, trim

I have a string:

```
\n\n\n\Mytext is here\n new line \n\n
```

with an unknown amount of \n at the beginning and at the end.

How can I trim this string to

```
Mytext is here\n new line
```

in an elegant way?

I know I could code this with my own function. But, perhaps there is a simple solution?

Comment: The answer from ross is ok, but it's not null save. Which could be done by hand or for example using a simple lib like apache commons lang StringUtils which is nullsave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trim it, using [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method of `String` which "*Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.*"

Note that it *Returns a copy of the string* and doesn't edit the `String`

```
myString.trim()
```

**Null Strings**

As @rmertins said, this is not "null safe", meaning if your `String` is `null` it will throw a `NullPointerException` so if your `String` can be `null`, wrap it.

```
if (myString != null)
{
  String newTrimmedString = myString.trim();
}
```

Importing an entire library to do this one task like @rmertins said (i.e. [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from apache commons) is just overkill I'd say.  I would also say it's bad practice to pass around `null` objects anyhow and `null` `String` objects suggests bad design.

**What is removed**

It's worth noting that @JohnyTex pointed out that all characters below \u0020 are removed by `trim()` including carriage return and line-feed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its a shame. Now after about 5 Java coding I did not know that. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Note that all letters below \u0020 are removed with trim(), i.e. also carriage return and line-feed etc.

Comment: Thanks @JohnyTex, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`String.trim()` will trim away white space at the beginning and end. That would probably be the quickest way. If you need to retain other white spaces and only want to remove the `\n`, I think you would have to replace them manually.

You could try something along the lines of

`myString = myString.replace("^(\n)*","").replace("(\n)*$","");`

(I have not tried this code.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [String.trim() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

```
String foo = "\n\n  \n\t actual Value\t\n \n ";
System.out.println(foo.trim()); //prints "actual Value"
```

About as simple and elegant as it gets. Keep in mind, though, that this will not only trim newline characters, but tabs, spaces, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is potentially `null`, you might want to use [`StringUtils.trim()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#trim-java.lang.String-) - the null-safe version of [`String.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()).